# sql select row if another doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with around one million entries that look like this:

```
TimeStamp                   TagName     Alarm Status
2017-08-02 10:53:10.000     XS-101      Alarm
2017-08-02 18:49:45.000     XS-201      Alarm
2017-08-03 01:08:16.000     XS-101      Normal
2017-08-05 09:16:42.000     XS-301      Alarm
2017-08-12 12:33:39.000     XS-101      Alarm
```

I need to figure out which TagName has been in alarm the longest, but I don't care if it's not currently in alarm. I can do this with with my program code, but all of my program's other SQL queries return exactly what I need. Is it possible to do this with only SQL?

I've searched around for examples where people are returning rows based on the contents of other rows, but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Hi @Ken, do you have your attempted SQL Syntax? Perhaps it's just a minor tweak that you are missing. This is a simple MAX(TimeStamp) GROUP BY [Alarm Status] query. Did you try searching for MAX functions?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 I did, but I didn't see how I would filter out the tags that aren't currently in alarm.

Comment: Post your attempted syntax and let us take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which tag is in alarm the longest is asking which tag has the oldest current alarm code.

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select tagname, max(timestamp)
from t
group by tagname
having max(timestamp) = max(case when status = 'Alarm' then timestamp end)
order by max(timestamp) asc;
```

This assumes that two alarms are not in sequence for the same tag -- this is consistent with your described data.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the 'having' gets me a lot closer. I didn't know about that.  But how would you handle the Normal conditions? If a tag's last event was a Normal, then it isn't currently in alarm and doesn't need to be in the final results.  Should I run the same query again on the Normals, join them on the tag names, and then choose whichever has the latest time stamp?

Comment: @Ken . . . This handles the Normals.  Only tags where the most recent timestamp is `'Alarm'` are in the result set.

Comment: You're right. Your example works perfectly on the example data. When asking though, I forgot that I also have Acknowledge events in my table. So that threw me off when trying to understand your code. Filtering those events out before running your solution gives the results that I expected. Thanks for the help.